# Find active users using MongoDB's aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections — `customers` and `trips`:

An example document in **customers** where `_id` is a unique ID assigned to each customer:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("59caa2660d09740010eccfde")
}
```

An example document in **trips** where `userId` is the `_id` of the customer who took the trip, `duration` is the trip duration in minutes and `endtime` is the time at which that particular trip ended (`_id` here doesn't really matter):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59fe73be50fe7600169bcdb5"),
    "userId": ObjectId("59caa2660d09740010eccfde"),
    "duration": NumberInt(54),
    "endtime": ISODate("2017-11-03T08:14:45.193+0000")
}
```

On using `$lookup` to "left outer join" `trips` to `customers`, I have several hundred documents and each customer has trips (zero or more) associated with them:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("59caa2660d09740010eccfde"),
    "trips": [
      {
          "_id" : ObjectId("59fe73be50fe7600169bcdb5"),
          "userId": ObjectId("59caa2660d09740010eccfde"),
          "duration": NumberInt(54),
          "endtime": ISODate("2017-11-03T08:14:45.193+0000")
      },
      {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5a5acb708e303e00109820ac"),
          "userId": ObjectId("59caa2660d09740010eccfde"),
          "duration": NumberInt(32),
          "endtime": ISODate("2018-01-14T03:15:59.207+0000")
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to fetch all active customers where an active customer is anyone who:

- Takes at least 7 trips a week OR has 5 hours of trip time per week
- Maintained the above for at least 2 weeks in the last 4 weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to have the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** pipeline stage as the last or one of the last after grouping the trips collection calculating the aggregates and then filter.

So, for the first condition you need to get all the last four weeks documents from the trips collection, group them by `userId` and one week interval and aggregate the times:

```
var fourWeeksAgo = new Date();
fourWeeksAgo.setDate(fourWeeksAgo.getDate() - 28);

// var fourWeeksAgo = moment().subtract(4, "weeks").toDate();

db.trips.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "endtime": { "$gte": fourWeeksAgo } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "user": "$userId",
                "weekInterval": {
                    "$subtract": [
                        { 
                            "$subtract": ["$endtime", new Date("1970-01-01")] 
                        },
                        { 
                            "$mod": [
                                { "$subtract": ["$endtime", new Date("1970-01-01")] },
                                1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "totalDuration": { "$sum": "$duration" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.user",
            "weekCounts": {
                "$push": {
                    "week": "$weekInterval",
                    "count": "$count",
                    "duration": "$totalDuration"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "weekCounts.1": { "$exists": true },
            "$or": [
                { "weekCounts.count": { "$gte": 7 } },
                { "weekCounts.duration": { "$gte": 300 } }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "user"
        }           
    }
])
```

Comment: I ran the above code on my Mongo shell and got `1513612041397` as the result. Can't understand why.

Comment: What do you get when you run the aggregate operation with just the first pipeline step `var fourWeeksAgo = new Date();
fourWeeksAgo.setDate(fourWeeksAgo.getDate() - 28);

db.trips.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "endtime": { "$gte": fourWeeksAgo } } } ]);`?

Comment: Something similar — `1513615497362`

Comment: And what if you change the date variable `var oneDayAgo = new Date(); oneDayAgo.setDate(oneDayAgo.getDate() - 1); db.trips.aggregate([ { "$match": { "endtime": { "$lte": oneDayAgo } } } ]);`? If you are getting just the timestamp it means there are no matching documents in your collection.

Comment: The output is the timestamp again — `1515958106233`. There should be matching documents in my `trips` collection though. I can see them when I print all trips.

Comment: What do you get with the query `db.trips.find({}).sort({'endtime': -1}).limit(2)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163233/discussion-between-daksh-shah-and-chridam).